# С чего начать при написании скрипта?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день!

Как правильно писать скрипты? С чего начинать? Какова логика написания?

Как отладить скрипт? 
Как выяснить почему не работает та или иная функция, которая вроде в других подобных моментах работает.

Курсы проходил, но как-то не особо. Вроде мелкие могу писать, что-то типа, нажал тут, скрылось там, а вот те, которые сложнее никак.

Вот например задача: есть форма, и кнопка отправки, которая находится вне формы.  Нужно отключить отправку этой формы.

Вроде всё просто, нужно отключить через

```
 $('.b-form--order').submit(function(){
  return false;
 });

 <form>
    <input type="text" class"form-input">
 </form>
```

Отправить

но скрипт не работает. Почему он не срабатывает? Как выяснить?

Comment: Что значит отключить отправку этой формы?

Comment: В подобных вопросах - **почему не работает** очень помогает инструмент разработчика в браузере (например в **chrome**). А именно - консоль. В ней Вы можете имулировать различные действия скрипта. Например, в Вашем случае: возможно, у вас не правильно указан `selector ('.b-form--order')`. Напишите в консоли `$('.b-form--order')` и посмотрите, нашелся ли у Вас элемент.

Comment: Коммент сверху правильно описывает проблему, у вас нет элемента `.b-form--order`, но Вы к нему обращаетесь, можно поменять на тег `form`, либо присвоить идентификатор тегу `<form>`

Answer (score 1):

Для начала лучше всего дожидаться загрузки страницы `document.onReady`. Для этого в jQuery есть шаблон:

```
$(function() {
 // твой код, когда страница загружена
})
```

В твоем примере ты используешь селектор `$('.b-form--order')`, которого на странице ещё нет (даже если бы он был, т.к. у тебя он не указан). 
Но если сделать:

```
$(function() {
   $('.b-form--order').submit(function(){
      return false;
   });
});
```

Ты повесишь обработчик тогда, когда страница будет полностью готова и элементы на ней будут полностью сформированы.

А в твоем примере нужно поправить тег `<form>` на `<form class="b-form--order">`.

P.S. Лучше делать идентификаторы у элементов `<form id="myForm">`, тогда обращаться будешь так: `$('#myForm')`. Такой подход работает быстрее. Но в случаях когда тебе надо выбрать множество элементов, можно использовать класс.

**Живой пример:**

```js
$(function() {
  $('.b-form--order').submit(function() {
    console.log('Submited!');
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="b-form--order">
  <input type="text" class "form-input">
</form>
```

**На codepen:**

http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/jqLEGm?editors=1111

Comment: если поменять местами форму и скрипт то можно и не _дожидаться загрузки страницы document.onReady_.

Comment: _<form class=".b-form--order">_ = классы в html - обычно без точек

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо за поправку, задумался видимо. Вопрос был про написание скрипта, а обрамлять скрипты лучше в методы, когда страница загружена, чтобы не было проблем со вставкой их в любое место на странице. Он спросил про подход, я ответил.

Comment: ну, кстати, подход: размещать скрипты в конце страницы, вполне себе популярен, и при его использовании не надо думать про ready

Comment: Я не сторонник этого, но это тоже правильный подход. Как всегда и у всего, есть несколько вариантов решения.

Comment: Да, забыл просто в примере добавить класс, с классом тоже не хочет работать, могут ли другие скрипты перекрывать мой скрипт?

Comment: @drtvader, приведите [mcve], чтобы было видно какой именно код у вас не работает

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за ссылку! Мне бы просто понять, с чего начинать при написании скрипта. Какая логика при написании программы.

Comment: Вот пример, все работает, в консоль пишет `submited!`, когда отправляете форму с помощью `Enter` http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/jqLEGm?editors=1111

Comment: понял, спасибо!